# Getting SID from win32_groupuser

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi

I am trying to get the SIDs of users and groups by querying

```
get-wmiobject -query 'select groupcomponent,partcomponent from win32_groupuser`
```

output:

```
__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : Win32_GroupUser
__SUPERCLASS     :
__DYNASTY        :
__RELPATH        : Win32_GroupUser.GroupComponent="\\\\COMPUTER\\root\\cimv2:Win32_Group.Domain=\"TESTDOMAIN\",Name=\
                   "Schema Admins\"",PartComponent="\\\\COMPUTER\\root\\cimv2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain=\"TESTDOMAIN\"
                   ,Name=\"Administrator\""
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 2
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         :
__NAMESPACE      :
__PATH           :
GroupComponent   : \\COMPUTER\root\cimv2:Win32_Group.Domain="TESTDOMAIN",Name="Schema Admins"
PartComponent    : \\COMPUTER\root\cimv2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain="TESTDOMAIN",Name="Administrator"
```

`groupcomponent` is a `win32_group` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

`win32_group` is contains an SID (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394151%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#)

However the groupcomponent here is a string and not a win32_group as

```
get-wmiobject -query 'select groupcomponent.sid from win32_groupuser'
```

is an invalid query.
How can I access `groupcomponent`'s members as a `win32_group`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PartComponent Property contains the SID. Access it by iterating through all objects via WMI:

```
gwmi win32_groupuser | % { [wmi]$_.partcomponent }
```

or use

```
gwmi win32_groupuser | % { [wmi]$_.partcomponent | select SID }
```

to only receive the SID.

Comment: How would I use this from vbscript? I'm currently using a query so I can do 
`objWMIService.ExecQuery("select partcomponent,groupcomponent from win32_groupuser")`, however that doesn't work with the commands above.

Comment: @AG hmm i'm not quite sure about VB, and I never wrote a VB-Script. Always using PowerShell. You should ask this in a new question, and accept this as an answer, since your original question has been answered.