# Accessing underlying object of SWbemObject instance

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript, wmi

I'm using vbscript to interact with the WMI classes. I am querying the `Win32_GroupUser` class which is defined here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

In the definition, it has the following components:

```
class Win32_GroupUser : CIM_Component
{
  Win32_Group   REF GroupComponent;
  Win32_Account REF PartComponent;
};
```

My vbscript is as follows:

```
dim objWMIService, o, obj, test, test1, strComputer
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\"& strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
set obj = objWMIService.ExecQuery("select partcomponent,groupcomponent from win32_groupuser")

for each o in obj
    set test = objWMIService.ReferencesTo(o.groupcomponent)
    wscript.echo o.groupcomponent
    set test1 = test.itemindex(0)
    wscript.echo "test is a "&typename(test)&", test1 is a "&typename(test1)
    on error resume next
    for each j in test1.methods_ 'list all methods
        wscript.echo "Method: "&j.name
    next
    for each j in test1.properties_ 'list all properties
        wscript.echo "Property: "&j.name
    next
    i = test1.properties_("GroupComponent")
    wscript.echo "Groupcomponent is a " & typename(i)
    wscript.echo "GroupComponent: "&i

next
```

The output is

```
\\COMPUTER\root\cimv2:Win32_Group.Domain="TESTDOMAIN",Name="Schema Admins"
test is a SWbemObjectSet, test1 is a SWbemObjectEx
Property: GroupComponent
Property: PartComponent
Groupcomponent is a String
Groupcomponent: \\COMPUTER\root\cimv2:Win32_NTDomain.Name="Domain: TESTDOMAIN"
```

However I am having trouble trying to follow the reference to the `GroupComponent`; it keeps on coming out as a **string** and not as a **win32_group** object, hence I cannot access the properties such as SID etc.

How do I access the groupcomponent as a win32_group object and not as the string?

Comment: Not sure why you keep asking the [same](http://superuser.com/questions/1070852/complex-wmi-queries-using-execquery) [question](http://superuser.com/questions/1070466/getting-sid-from-win32-groupuser) repeatedly.  Please update the original with new info instead of asking the same thing again.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 the first question was about powershell, this question is about doing the same thing in vbscript. I'd say it's better to ask a new question, than to update the PowerShell question.

Comment: I was told to ask it in a new question instead of updating the original with new info; this question is about following references in a wmi object in vb script. The first question you reference is asking about how to link queries in vb script, giving a powershell query as an example.
The second question you reference was asking how to get create the correct query in powershell.

Comment: I wonder whether these questions would get better results at [SO].